# Current Password issue for New Register User

Tags: 7, users

My registeraion is set to "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account" on Drupal 7. Any user who register will automatically receive a confirmation email with "One time login url". However the problem is, user does not have the "Current Password" to set their new password. How can I fix this?

**PS: user does have current password on database "users" table**

**added info:**
**using module [logintoboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)**

---

**added on July 2nd:**
I found a similar issue from [Durupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1579806), but i dont wanna use another module to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

with the one time login the user is logged in automatically and he can set the password without inserting the current one.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the current password is requested when I use the one time login url. I got the error message if not insert the "Current Password". Here is the error message "Your current password is missing or incorrect; it's required to change the Password."

Comment: be careful, you need to login and set the password straight after your click the one time login link. if it does not work there must be something wrong with your drupal installation

Comment: is there something to do with logintoboggan module?

Comment: I dont think so...I made this short video for you. This is how my test installation of drupal works: http://youtu.be/Yn6g33kjlI4

Comment: i can't see this video. It said this video is private

Comment: sorry...try it now

Comment: Hi, the video you have is different. You are using the Request new password tab (domain.com/user/register). My question is, an url from the register confirmation email. This "One time login url" pointing you to your account. However, in order to set my password, I need to insert my "current password". Which I dont have one during register.

Comment: when a user registers gets the same One time login url one gets when asks for a new password...if not, you probably accidentally changed the Activation email body. Check it in admin/config/people/accounts and make sure there is [user:one-time-login-url] in the email body of "Account activation"

Comment: yes, the "[user:one-time-login-url]" is on "Account activation" body. It only allow registered user to login once. The issue is when I want to set my password thru this URL, the current password is requested, which I dont have.